# C - Convert time_t to string with format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: c

Is there any way to convert a `time_t` to a `std::string` with the format **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** automatically while keeping the code portable?

Answer (score 74):

Use `localtime` to convert the `time_t` to a `struct tm`. You can use `strftime` to print the desired data from that.

```
#include <time.h>
...
char buff[20];
time_t now = time(NULL);
strftime(buff, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
```

Comment: +1 good answer.  But use localtime_r() in case your code is ever used in a re-entrant environment.

Comment: @Amardeep: He specifically asked for portability, and `localtime_r` may not qualify in that regard (depends on what targets he cares about).

Comment: localtime_r has been part of POSIX for 18 years at this point.  I think it's safe to assume it'll be available.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell: at least from my perspective, restricting yourself to POSIX is essentially synonymous with "not portable". There's not a single OS with a large enough market share to notice that makes a serious attempt at implementing POSIX accurately (and yes, I'm aware of Linux, but aware that its POSIX conformance is spotty, at best).

Comment: @JerryCoffin then what would you consider portable?  ...and it's not just Linux, *BSD, Solaris (ish), OSX and even Windows (ish) provide POSIX compliant APIs.  For networking especially they're not 100% identical/compliant, but for simple utility functions like strlen, time, localtime, they're pretty similar if not identical in the way they interpret the POSIX standard(s).

Comment: `strlen`, `time` and `localtime` are quite portable because they're in the C standard. `localtime_r` isn't nearly so universally supported--just for example, it appears that neither of the compilers I have on Windows includes it.

Answer (score 0):

Your only real option off the top of my head is either to write your own routine, or use the ctime() function defined in POSIX.1/C90. ctime() is certainly worth looking into, but if your date is not in the right timezone already, you will run into issues.

EDIT: I didn't think about using localtime as mentioned by Jerry below. Converting it to a struct tm does give you more possibilities including what he mentions, and strptime().

Comment: Nope, strftime was mentioned, but strptime was not, they are two separate (yet similar) functions. However, while strftime is part of C90, strptime is not, so if it doesn't exist on the platforms you target, ignore that part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a function that can be called at multiple points in your code you can try this. It is based on the top answer, which you really should mark as accepted btw...

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

std::string get_localtime() {
    char buffer[80];
    std::time_t now = std::time(nullptr);
    std::strftime(buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
    std::string result(buffer);
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.