# Format and display Time on Photon

Tags: c++

I'm trying to display the current time on the OLED board attached to my Particle Photon.

```
void loop() {
  time_t time = Time.now();
  Time.format(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z');
  displayString(time);
}

int displayString(String text) {
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,0);
  display.println(text);
  display.display();

  return 1;
}
```

I have confirmed that `displayString` works. As it is an embedded device, you don't have access to the regular time library, however the Photon has it's own.

https://docs.particle.io/reference/firmware/core/#time

I'm getting the error `Invalid conversion from int to const char*`.

---

**Edit:** For anyone else who comes across this, I discovered that while undocumented, if you do not provide a time it will use the current time, so you can just do:

```
String time = Time.format("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S");
```

The uppercase `String` type is intentional, see [String class](https://docs.particle.io/reference/firmware/core/#string-class).

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: @Ben Line 3 (Time.format...)

Comment: Someone had the same issue, the posted solution seems good : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053999/c-convert-time-t-to-string-with-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss

Comment: @loopingz I dont think this is the problem, given the OP's example link, this should work. The OP has made a multi-character char instead of a string though.

Comment: @Ben yes sorry i haven't seen that the library Time was handling it already, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because in this line:

```
Time.format(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z');
```

you specify the format string as a `multi-character char`, not a `string`. Try:

```
Time.format(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"); // Note the double quotation marks
```

Just for some more information about multi-character chars read here: [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)

Also pay attention to your compiler warnings, you should have received this:

> warning: multi-character character constant

Which would have alerted you to this problem.

Comment: I didn't catch that at first glance, nice eyes.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this, I discovered that while undocumented, if you do not provide a time it will use the current time, so you can just do: `String time = Time.format("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S");`.