# Send a time_t with UDP protocol

Tags: c

I'm trying to send a time_t value over a UDP socket. I think that I need to convert it into a string, save int the buffe and send.
After a research in internet, I tried with the snprintf() function, but I don't know why does not work.

```
snprintf(buffer, BUF_SIZE, "%s", puntatore_list->date);
```

puntatore_list->date is the time_t value.

Is the correct way to do?

Comment: Why not just send the struct itself?

Comment: If you want to send it as a string, take a look at the first answer on this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053999/c-convert-time-t-to-string-with-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss

If you just want to send the timestamp, you will have to take endianness into account. (As with sending any multi-byte datatype.)

Comment: @gspr I did't know that could be this possibility..

Comment: @MatthiasRaba Thanks, now I'm trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both sides of the communication have the same definition of `time_t` (and the same [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)), you can just send it: `send(sock, &(puntatore_list->date), sizeof(time_t), NULL)`.

If not, just agree on a common definition (for example "number of second since some agreed-upon point in time stored as a 64 bit integer") and convert from `time_t` to that before sending.

Comment: And, on the receiver side, I write
`recvfrom(sd, *(my_list->date), sizeoof(time_t),....)`

Comment: The corresponding `recv`/`recvfrom` call. Before I give an example of that: would you know how to send and receive a basic data type like an `int` or a `char` across UDP? (You should definitely work out how to do that beore getting into the whole business of time…)

Comment: After your comment's edit: almost right. That should be `&(my_list->date)`. `recvfrom` wants an address to write its result to, so if `my_list->date` has type `time_t`, you need to get its address (through `&`).

Comment: But if this is new to you, it could be a good idea to begin simpler. I'd first try to make sure you manage to send and receive a single `char`. Then an `int` (first problem that arises: potential size and endianness difference between the sender and receiver). Then `size_t` (same problem as for `int`, plus a potentially different reference point for "time 0").

Comment: `have the same definition of time_t` and the same endianess

Comment: Another possibility is using textual based protocols, à la [JSON](http://json.org/) or like HTTP

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
snprintf(buffer, BUF_SIZE, "%ld", (long) puntatore_list->date);
```

and send it as a string of digits.

By the way, have you tried to output your version to `stdout` to see what is printed?

The `%ld` format allows you to format a `long` number (most probably your `time_t` is a `long` or `unsigned long`) as a string of ascii digits, to ensure you can cast the value to `(long)` so you avoid the need to know the actual implementation type and depend on the definition of `time_t`.

This method also allows you to use a common format for transmitter and  receiver, so in the case both machines use different architecture to represent a `time_t` value, you can use a system independent format that will appear the same on both machines.